# Git create branch from master and rebase on top

Tags: git

I have following repository

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L
```

And I want to do:

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L
   \
    C-D-E-F-G-H
```

And move new branch on top of master

```
A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L
                       \
                        C-D-E-F-G-H
```

So I did:

```
checkout B
checkout -b new-branch
cherry-pick C D E F G H
// so far it what i want
rebase new-branch master
// now I'm back in master like I did nothing
```

Not sure how to achieve this.

// EDIT

Commit `I` is Revert from github UI, so it's commits `C-D-E-F-G-H` squashed together. (Or `I` is merge commit and `J` is revert commit.)

Comment: Why do you think you need some commits to appear twice in the history? Looks like an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem more than anything.

Comment: @RomainValeri I updated question. I is revert commit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want commit C, D, E, F, G, H on their own branch without I, J , K, and L, you should do this:

```
git checkout H
git checkout -b new-branch
```

After adding a few more commits on new-branch, your history would look like:

```
master:    A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L
                          \
new-branch:                M-N-O
```

Once you have worked on new-branch some and have some commits, you can use rebase to play the differing commits on top of master like this:

```
git checkout new-branch
git rebase master
```

That would make your history look like this:

```
master:    A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-J-K-L
                                  \
new-branch:                        M-N-O
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to cherry-pick a range of desired commits directly from master.

```
git cherry-pick C..H
```

Comment: What is the difference between cherry-pick range of commits and list of the same commits?

Comment: I don't think there is any except for convenience, you can even apply those one by one.